# How to properly animate using CSS in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a side-project website for myself using React to get a better understanding of it. I'm trying to animate a div to fade in when the user scrolls to its position. I've successfully worked the on-scroll event to trigger a function which changes the class name of the div (according to my understanding this should trigger the transition in opacity). However, this doesn't work; instead this leads to a display of only the text within the div, with no animation what so ever. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm setting the class name of the div but not sure what, here is the code:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: "WhatIdo",
      firstTransitionPosition: 0
    }
    this.handleScroll = this.checkForScroll.bind(this)
    this.hasBeenSet = false
  }

  checkForScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY >= this.state.firstTransitionPosition && this.hasBeenSet == false) {
      console.log("this event is triggering")
      this.setState({name: "WhatIdo--visible"})
      this.hasBeenSet = true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var transitionComp = this.refs.moveMe
    var topOfElement = transitionComp.getBoundingClientRect().top
    var heightOfElement = transitionComp.getBoundingClientRect().height
    this.setState({firstTransitionPosition: topOfElement - heightOfElement})
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1 className="PageTitle">Portfolio</h1>
        <div className="AboutMe">
          some stuff here
        </div>
        <div ref="moveMe" className={this.state.name}>
          some more random stuff
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the CSS:

```
.AboutMe {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thick;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 365px;
  bottom: 300px;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 2; }
}

.WhatIdo {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thick;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 365px;
  bottom: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.WhatIdo--visible {
  opacity: 1
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Opacity doesn't take numbers higher than 1. It's a "percentage" value from 0 to 1 (0.5 for 50%, for example)

Comment: @SimonNußbaumer thanks for noticing that! I've fixed that up. The main error in the display still persists though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something... when you change `this.state.name` from `WhatIdo` to `WhatIdo--visible` you're losing all the styles of the `WhatIdo` class, including the `transition` property, which causes it to just pop in.

Find a way to specify that the element should be visible *in addition to* retaining its normal styles. For instance, you could simply add the `visible` class to the element, and have the CSS definition be `.WhatIdo.visible` so that it overrides the others.

One way (out of many) would be to use a template string and modify your state to simply specify whether the element visibility is true or false, making it a bit more abstract and flexible with how you respond to state changes:

```
    <div ref="moveMe" className={`WhatIdo ${this.state.isVisible ? "visible" : ""}`}>
      some more random stuff
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this works perfectly; Ive added an isVisible property to state which is set to true or false based on the scroll position and then applied the rest of your answer which works a treat. marked as correct answer :)